# vmware_guest_snapshot: ERROR! no action detected in task

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I've an issue with a really basic module which doesn't seem do work like it is supposed to work, I guess?

I actually copied the part out of the documentation.

My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Create Snapshot
      vmware_guest_snapshot:
        hostname: vSphereIP
        username: vSphereUsername
        password: vSpherePassword
        name: vmname
        state: present
        snapshot_name: aSnapshotName
        description: aSnapshotDescription
```

I run this playbook from ansible tower and it throws "ERROR! no action detected in task". It seems like a syntax error for me but I literaly copied it over from the documentation and other modules are working with the same syntax.

So does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [`vmware_guest_snapshot` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_guest_snapshot_module.html) is available since version 2.3 of Ansible (which is not yet released).

If you are running any older version, the module name will not be recognised and Ansible will report the error `no action detected in task`.

Currently you need to be [running Ansible from source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source) (the `devel` branch) to run the `vmware_guest_snapshot` module.

Comment: This is a nice info to have. Thank you!